# heroku fork fails with Cisaurus copy service no longer available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fork

When forking a heroku app, I get the message "Cisaurus copy service no longer available. Use Heroku Platform API instead." No gem by that title is installed. What is causing this? Full output below, using [myapp] in place of the sourceapp name, and [targetapp] in place of the forked copy name:

```
[myapp]$ heroku fork -a [myapp] [targetapp]
Creating fork [targetapp]... done
Copying slug... Failed to fork app [myapp] to [targetapp].

 !    WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
 !    This command will destroy edmeasured-sandbox (including all add-ons).
 !    To proceed, type "[targetapp]" or re-run this command with --confirm 
[targetapp]


> [targetapp]
Deleting [targetapp]... done
Original exception below:
 !    Cisaurus copy service no longer available. Use Heroku Platform API     instead. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-copying-slugs
[targetapp]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is being caused by using an old version of Heroku Toolbelt. Updating via https://toolbelt.heroku.com allows the command to run as intended.